# How can I send an HTTP request from my FastAPI app to another site (API)?

Tags: python, async-await, httprequest, python-asyncio, fastapi

I am trying to send 100 requests at a time to a server `http://httpbin.org/uuid` using the following code snippet

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import sleep
from time import time
import requests
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

URL= "http://httpbin.org/uuid"


# @app.get("/")
async def main():
    r = requests.get(URL)
    # print(r.text)
    
    return r.text

async def task():
    tasks = [main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main(),main()]
    # print(tasks)
    # input("stop")
    result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print (result)

@app.get('/')
def f():
    start = time()
    asyncio.run(task())
    print("time: ",time()-start)
```

I am using FastAPI with Asyncio to achieve the lowest time possible around 3 seconds or less but using the above method I am getting an overall time of 66 seconds that is more than a minute. I also want to keep the `main` function for additional operations on `r.text`. I understand that to achieve such low time, concurrency is required but I am not sure what mistake I'm doing here.

Comment: even with curl i'm getting 0.111 ms for 100 requests `time for _ in {1..100}; do curl http://httpbin.org/uuid & done` this is pretty weird.

Comment: it's because each curl is splitting into a different process but the same thing is not working in my code - https://imgur.com/a/pmh7qLb `time for _ in {1..100}; do curl http://httpbin.org/uuid & done && ps aux | grep curl
`

Comment: IKR i was talking about this, asyncio should behave exactly like curl, i tried on my machine with different approach that didn't worked out too, then i thinked about uvicorn is just an another event loop maybe it's the issue, after that i ran it normally, also it took so long tho..

Comment: Also i'm using this pattern for asyncio, which looks pretty solid for me, i created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ycd/725017df88bb3d9378e76d06d83738f4) you might want to check it out

Comment: Yep, Even I find this right.

Comment: My machine died thrice even for range(10).

Comment: So, a combination of asyncio and aiohttp would help in the case of URL request scenarios?

Comment: You could also try https://www.python-httpx.org/ . Create an AsyncClient with the base url, then use the client (equivalent of a `request` session) to perform 100 calls to the url

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this.

Comment: @johnmich hey, i needed to use my gist again, then I found I used `main()` inside main,  it should be working as expected now, sorry for killing your machine :(

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

`requests` is a synchronous library. You need to use an `asyncio`-based library to make requests asynchronously.

### [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/)

`httpx` is typically used in FastAPI applications to request external services. It provides synchronous and asynchronous clients which can be used in `def` and `async def` path operations appropriately. It is also recommended for [asynchronous tests](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/) of application. I would advice using it by default.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import time
import httpx
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

URL = "http://httpbin.org/uuid"


async def request(client):
    response = await client.get(URL)
    return response.text


async def task():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        tasks = [request(client) for i in range(100)]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(result)


@app.get('/')
async def f():
    start = time()
    await task()
    print("time: ", time() - start)
```

Output

```
['{\n  "uuid": "65c454bf-9b12-4ba8-98e1-de636bffeed3"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "03a48e56-2a44-48e3-bd43-a0b605bef359"\n}\n',...
time:  0.5911855697631836
```

### [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html)

`aiohttp` can also be used in FastAPI applications, if you prefer one.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from time import time
import aiohttp
import asyncio

app = FastAPI()

URL = "http://httpbin.org/uuid"


async def request(session):
    async with session.get(URL) as response:
        return await response.text()


async def task():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [request(session) for i in range(100)]
        result = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        print(result)


@app.get('/')
async def f():
    start = time()
    await task()
    print("time: ", time() - start)
```

---

If you want to limit the number of requests executing in parallel, you can use `asyncio.semaphore` like so:

```
MAX_IN_PARALLEL = 10
limit_sem = asyncio.Semaphore(MAX_IN_PARALLEL)


async def request(client):
    async with limit_sem:
        response = await client.get(URL)
        return response.text
```

Comment: You might want to create a single session in `task` and pass it to `main()`. That will allow aiohttp to be more efficient by e.g. reusing TCP connections.

Comment: "It is a dependency for FastAPI." - It's not.

Comment: This is a dependency only for `fastapi[test]`, so I removed the phrase to avoid confusing people.

Comment: @any reason to use httpx? versus aiohttp? I ask because httpx is considered to be in beta version, so in production, you want the "more" stable one, thx

Comment: @AlexJolig the [page](https://newbedev.com/how-can-i-send-an-http-request-from-my-fastapi-app-to-another-site-api) you've linked to is dated [2021-04-17](https://newbedev.com/t/fastapi).  This answer is dated 2020-09-14.  The page's title is identical to this question.  Perhaps you should direct your remark to the maintainer of that site, and retract your accusation towards this answer's author.

Comment: *"[B]ut do so if you really need it"* makes it sound like `aiohttp`, a well-known, established library, might cause significant problems in a FastAPI application, but your answer doesn't explain what those might be. Could you please [edit] your answer to explain?

Comment: @Julia, this will not cause any special problems, so I slightly corrected the answer

Comment: Great! Thank you, Alex!

Answer (score 2):

@Alex Noname has made a good point of using asynchronous request library. If you want to make code faster I would suggest using **asyncio.Queue** as an alternate. In this example I spun up 100 producers and 100 consumers. you can limit the maximum number of messages in the queue like, then producer waits until there is space for new message

> asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)

also I have made use of **AsyncClient** from **httpx**.

If you want to know more about queues I would suggest this article
https://realpython.com/async-io-python/

```
from time import time
from typing import List

from fastapi import FastAPI
from httpx import AsyncClient

app = FastAPI()

URL = "http://httpbin.org/uuid"
client = AsyncClient()


async def main():
    r = await client.get(URL)
    return r.text


async def producer(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    await queue.put(main)


async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue, resp: List):
    # await queue.get() == main  -> without arguments
    resp.append(await (await queue.get())())


async def task():
    q = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=100)
    response = []
    consumers = []
    producers = []
    [consumers.append(consumer(q, response)) for c in range(100)]
    [producers.append(producer(q)) for p in range(100)]

    await asyncio.gather(*producers)
    await asyncio.gather(*consumers)
    print(response)


@app.get('/')
def f():
    start = time()
    asyncio.run(task())
    print("time: ", time() - start)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    f()
```

output

```
['{\n  "uuid": "a7713d07-ea5d-40d3-95b4-6673f3c50a8b"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "c93f8b89-2c44-40fa-9e5f-736e22ad5f23"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "cbb4ad76-7790-45ae-87f1-e425eddc8021"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4c1d81c0-ae7d-401a-99df-e98af3651335"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "c5f70738-fbba-4cf9-8fdf-29f8b4eabe63"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "d016b852-4312-4502-a336-a6a110237d1d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "22d8b00b-4266-4236-b5a3-ed5d7c5be416"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "cd54fdbb-7de9-4df3-90cc-e6b108d5fdf8"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "757f0a26-7896-4a04-bea2-60c66a38b05b"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "72eb6584-21f4-449b-b6bd-d0f88666126f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b3deadf5-5b79-491b-829c-0404c306cb68"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "789e7422-493d-49d2-9585-e5ca34b7cf36"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "48d29a82-ff7c-41f5-8af2-42784326a31f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "84b2d67c-331c-4037-b6e4-c299d93c1899"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "386e79f9-073a-4f27-961c-7befcdf95cd4"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "8dfdb5e4-dd69-4043-b174-48ec8505f36f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "633e634b-b107-42bb-a7d3-c6bbfff089a0"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "962d665f-8663-4be7-a3c6-9426ba500bf4"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "320fb858-a751-4c34-9cdb-ddd2f4e28efa"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "46a75693-5255-4ac7-8d7a-54910b4d6f68"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "5323734b-7ff9-455e-ba5a-66383e6b9a1f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "622a579f-35b6-4e4b-9dba-a8a69c2049c8"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "593d5e82-cef3-4be0-99ab-e3034855d7a1"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "80f139df-2a27-40c1-8329-e4faa035c45c"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a97e084c-4d30-4c7b-a96e-89ed00dcfe2a"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "360d49eb-7222-4064-81c2-6eba2d43a9a5"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a81b6eab-a646-4e58-b986-96a90baa52aa"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "0160337e-b400-41d6-ae89-aa46c5131f40"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e600722f-8c15-4959-948b-4c4e5296feb2"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "f15403e4-3674-43b2-a0c9-649fd828ba7e"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "36bf139c-cc18-45a8-bc55-e7f90ce290b5"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b2368a3c-d86b-4fcd-a0d3-bf7f8f657a83"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "d9f16c36-3572-4c70-8a41-3d4e279d76bf"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "796087cc-a202-40dd-9921-14802a73323d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "089fa0d7-4c48-4daa-a80d-cb5ebd37dfb7"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e5582bc7-0f8a-4da7-b640-79a0d812154d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "bac0640b-0d0b-4bf2-a3c1-36bdda7cce03"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b4353004-02b2-4846-8692-33dd77ad1d3f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "1b34a744-d0ea-4acf-8bda-33743800d86a"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4d9dd269-6ee2-4356-9bc4-ddf188445320"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a1f380df-0c0d-4aee-bbb7-c3e99fbfe54f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "7cb762eb-1a42-433d-97ea-aa9de4504e35"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "981c40e2-64bf-4746-8103-9430bda2a5ca"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "22b778eb-82d1-48b9-9874-5ebb80ddb8b1"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e7a9e0e8-7964-400c-aafe-9c36b9b7e1a0"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "21a59b91-2732-4bb6-a47e-84008a03c20c"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a78eeb39-5ecb-4509-87c2-b4a2529e3536"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4a332579-ce03-4f69-9db5-78da9196d6b2"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "55fbc34f-4eb3-4356-98e3-1df38054a4b2"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "257ac454-09c2-4fd4-bdb3-303495360fa2"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "7505cc0d-01b3-47f8-91d4-3e54d0f387de"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "0fd67af2-622e-4688-b3c8-f64e20f1f3ec"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "07653ccf-f408-4807-8ff5-e6098d657451"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b9d0ff18-fd67-4afa-adbe-ebcb53380804"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "70d4d53b-2f06-41be-bb38-47f010cfa40f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a6d49873-e749-4578-ae9c-e6c6f473535d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e67efee5-76ad-4812-bb97-016ef9ff87e8"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "67886926-b2d9-44fb-b836-26b81c53e5fb"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "dcbd4ff8-e3cd-4e03-b12d-5fb3834b0e00"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "65c2eaee-5fa2-4b58-a1c3-adeb04d92c71"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "2cee4ec9-952e-45c5-91b7-f4f5848c3455"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "8e94bf1c-ee5a-483a-a962-d0b9aea48c95"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "c1fe17bc-bedf-4c4c-952d-a5921f693d9f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "221456fd-48ca-4826-a8b5-5fa0b23db6e4"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "62fda759-b382-44e4-ad7d-d19a952fc1c7"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "73faeb91-215e-4e49-8f11-11b98e499cc7"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "f3279c45-ebcc-4079-b823-3efe825c7cf8"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b892672b-4510-44f4-b61e-9cccaa52421e"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "8926979d-71a7-4171-9389-ddafff89e229"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "d97cef59-4862-42ca-b0f2-261f98fd4b6f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "3362ff93-89e4-4889-a2f2-2e03771e86ce"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "9f525251-4fe4-4a9c-97b5-2f01d2b37aaf"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "036959d4-3179-40f9-bbf3-32274f2cede2"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "157f8c22-6214-4e27-ab5d-08d39f96d1d3"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e4bfbf62-7c33-4fd7-a231-47f5ce398041"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a41512c1-3346-4457-a379-64d690ffc2ea"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "7bb07cfb-294b-44fa-a8dc-6d283c54409f"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "f2297d22-a2d0-47ff-8d65-24c6fe7877a7"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "645e255b-4c93-4c8f-9ff2-43da293db660"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "9190e370-dfa9-47a6-8cef-8df7ab762433"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "83216551-9f1b-48b2-8cd6-fd125a7ce965"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "aaddb98c-879b-472d-aa39-1a684ef7d179"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4bd7e2fd-1453-4433-aa9f-bc29d82f5b9d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "b02d65e8-2063-4060-96af-088ec497fc10"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "e10e3dd2-83c5-4595-afe4-4145bce79193"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "8cb62784-1b5d-4dcc-8342-02ad7d417ca9"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "13ef1509-4f69-4426-ac42-cb29a2d0f094"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4d4571d5-69bb-4625-b246-b5eef50aa10d"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "75e7a2ca-bfa8-43b9-b33a-f3f927453579"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "0a8cc8ff-2039-4873-9e38-afad3e10d726"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "189ae75b-4879-4897-9725-f9be17e49844"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "ba482468-f45f-4060-a0c1-3ef31bb283c8"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "3809f1c7-2f11-487d-bf96-8abf64e08298"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "da5ea88b-974d-4238-9654-ac56c657c8b4"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "edc3de79-7cf4-42a3-a5f4-b754136a6fd3"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "6f5ecd91-537c-4009-8435-6c31ce035d36"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "4a33b29d-78ba-468f-8f30-a01b3d9e2a87"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "a5a2ef2d-d4a2-48e1-8335-f8c1309328c4"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "3d1679da-afdd-4f04-9c16-0aaea4c53d0c"\n}\n', '{\n  "uuid": "c4025845-0d4c-4549-acb8-1a249b33e644"\n}\n']
time:  1.0535461902618408
```

Comment: Can you explain how is this code faster than in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63881674/921269)? In the example there are couple programming flaws one might want to avoid, like appending an item to an external list inside a comprehension list instead of using the comprehension list directly. Also the code will hang forever when `q`'s `maxsize` is below 100, as the producers will eventually hang on `queue.put()` and so the `gather(*producers)` never completes. You'd have to schedule the two gathers as independent tasks, but that's not happening here. Downvoted.

Comment: what problem are you solving?