# How to asynchornously request multiple urls with requests and asyncio

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, generator, python-asyncio

I have a list of URL's which I would like asynchornously to be requested.

```
{'320193': {'year 1': 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-19-000119&xbrl_type=v', 'year 2': 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-18-000145&xbrl_type=v', 'year 3': 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=320193&accession_number=0000320193-17-000070&xbrl_type=v'}}
```

How could I go about doing this using asyncio and requests.  I am just learning about asyncio and generators so if you could try returning it as a generator that would be appreciated.

Comment: Requests isn't asyncio-aware. You'll have better luck with a library like aiohttp.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63881674/13782669