# asyncio - functions run sequentially instead of concurrently

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have a function that sends 2 different requests. I need to call this function with different parameters 20 times.

I would like to run the functions concurrently (different arguments) to spare some time between request and response.

This is a very simplified function:

```
async def get_data(url):
    return requests.get(url)
```

And this is how I call it:

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(get_data(url)) for url in websites.split('\n')]
group = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
print(results)
loop.close()
```

The problem is that it runs sequentially instead of concurrently.

It's obvious that I'm missing something. Do you know what to do?

Comment: Your code is going to run sequentially because requests isn't asyncio-aware. You'll want to use a library like aiohttp so that additional requests can be made while you're awaiting others.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63881674/13782669

Answer (score 2):

Don't wrap coroutine in `asyncio.create_task`, use `*` to unpack coroutins when passing to `asyncio.gather` and call `loop.run_until_complete` in the end

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [get_data(url) for url in websites.split('\n')]
group = asyncio.gather(*tasks)
results = loop.run_until_complete(group)
print(results)
loop.close()
```

Plus, it won't be concurrent because `requests` isn't asynchronous, it's blocking the thread, you need to use alternative async HTTP clients like [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp).

Comment: Thanks, this works but the problem is that it runs sequentially instead of concurrently.

Comment: What makes you think so?

Comment: I've added print(url) inside the function and it prints one after another with 1 - 3 second pauses.

Comment: Updated with a note