# What is the fastest way to take status codes of a huge URL list in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have spent some time to find the best and fastest way of getting status codes of a huge URL list but no progress.

Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def check(url):
    """Send request to url and get a HTTP status code"""
    try:
        response = requests.head(url)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
        return "404"
    return str(response.status_code)

def multiprocessing_func():
    url_list = [
        # A huge list of URLs
    ]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    start = time.time()
    pool.map(check, url_list)
    done = time.time()
    print("time: {}".format(done - start))
```

My laptop is a little bit slow, however:

when url_list has 1 URL, it takes 6 seconds to be done,

with 8 items, it takes 10 seconds,

with 32 items, it takes 24 seconds,

with 128 items, it takes 77 seconds and so on...

Why this time is growing in multiprocessing?

I think it should take nearly 6 or 7 seconds to be done(nearly the same amount of one URL).

What did I do wrong?

How can I do this in the fastest way (suppose I have a list with 10000 URLs)?

any suggestion would be appreciated.

best regards.

Comment: multiprocessing runs it on each individual core on your machine. try using `threading.Thread()` Especially when your computer is old and might only have 4 cores.

Comment: also, are you just looking for the status code of a page or the contents as well? @shahab

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm just looking for the status code, at the beginning I was using requests.get(url) and then changed it to requests.head(url) so the execution time decreased.

Comment: see my answer below. @shabab

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/63881674/13782669

Answer (score 1):

see async python calls [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/)

Python threading is not efficient due to [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use the `asyncio` and `aiohttp` modules for this. `threading` works as well though (with the caveat of being slightly slower).

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def check(url, session):
    session : aiohttp.ClientSession
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return response.status

async def multiprocessing_func():
    url_list = [
        #your huge list of urls :)
    ]
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in url_list:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(check(i, session)))
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(multiprocessing_func())
```

if you don't know what the poop is happening here, then I suggest that you read `asyncio` and `aiohttp`'s documentation

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but with this code when I double the URLs, the execution time doubles. for 32 items it took 26 seconds and for 64 items 50 seconds.

Comment: That I can't do anything about. The way that requests is structured is that your big O is n^2 (i.e when the inputs doubles the execution time doubles)