# fire and forget a post request using asyncio

Tags: python, post, async-await, python-requests, python-asyncio

I have to make a post request to an api, that api does some processing and takes around 5-10 mins to return. But I don't have to wait for that api to return. I just want to fire that api from my AWS Batch job and leave it.

```
def post_id(id):
   # this function does a post using requests library

async def submit_post_requests(id_list):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    excutor =  concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(THREAD_COUNT)
    for id in set(id_list):
        loop.run_in_executor(excutor, post_id, id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    id_list = [1,2,3]
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(submit_post_requests(id_list))
    print('reached end of program')
```

My code looks something like the above. When I run this it's reaching till the end of the program and printing `reached end of program` but the program is not exiting. Any suggestions on how we can exit the program without waiting for the post request to finish.

I know it's not a good practise to not wait for the post return but I don't have to wait for it and trying to exit the batch as quickly as can.

I am using this stack overflow questions as reference: [How could I use requests in asyncio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190403/how-could-i-use-requests-in-asyncio)

The only issue is the program not exiting till the coroutine finishes.

Comment: It's better to use asyncio-based lib. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872924/how-can-i-send-an-http-request-from-my-fastapi-app-to-another-site-api/63881674#63881674)

Comment: @alex_noname That's good general advice, but I'm not sure it solves the OP's issue, which is to send a request without waiting for a response. (I'm not sure it can be reliably done at all.)

Comment: @alex_noname even using the aiohttp, I still have to wait for it to exit. It doesn't work in my particular case.

Comment: You're right. With both, you can use a short timeout, but this does not guarantee that the request will reach the server. But you can choose a period that will (almost) always work in the given conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Program not exited because of threadsstill executing request.

Aiohttp or another will not start in this manner.

I suggest create detached and forked processes for this operations.