# Asyncio not running Aiohttp requests in parallel

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I want to run many HTTP requests in parallel using python.
I tried this module named aiohttp with asyncio.

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(10):
            async with session.get('https://httpbin.org/get') as response:
                html = await response.text()
                print('done' + str(i))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I expect it to execute all the requests in parallel, but they are executed one by one.
Although, I later solved this using threading, but I would like to know what's wrong with this?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/63872924/13782669

Comment: Related : https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html

Answer (score 16):

You need to make the requests in a concurrent manner. Currently, you have a single task defined by `main()` and so the `http` requests are run in a serial manner for that task.

You could also consider using [`asyncio.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) if you are using Python version `3.7+` that abstracts out creation of event loop:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def getResponse(session, i):
    async with session.get('https://httpbin.org/get') as response:
        html = await response.text()
        print('done' + str(i))

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [getResponse(session, i) for i in range(10)] # create list of tasks
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks) # execute them in concurrent manner

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: You can simplify the loop with list comprehension  `tasks = [asyncio.create_task(getResponse(session, i)) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: thanks for the feedback, list comprehension should definitely be preferred.

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much!

Comment: Unless you specifically need the `Task` associated with each `getResponse`, you can omit `create_task`. `[getResponse(session, i) for i in range(10)]`

Comment: I have used the above code.. once all the execution completed. again it executing and showing errors